# SQLite3 select Statement put's out data twice

Tags: php, sqlite

i went into php development again and wanted to just quickly write a little tool with SQLite3. I never worked with it before and now i get a kinda weird "error"?

My PHP Code and the SQL Statement seem to be ok as i can tell:

```
$results = $db->query('SELECT ID, LOCATION FROM table_name ');
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

And what i get is somehow irritating:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  ["ID"]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  string(4) "somewhere"
  ["LOCATION"]=>
  string(4) "somewhere"
}
```

I cannot see quite why i am getting every value twice. Maybe someone know what i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 2):

Literaly the first line in the documentation says:

SQLite3Result::fetchArray — Fetches a result row as an associative or numerically indexed array or both

Had to give fetchArray a parameter like:
fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)